# OleDbException was Unhandled - Crashes after a mins

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, dml

After approximately 40 seconds of running this code and inserting ~400 records into the table I get a

> OleDbException was Unhandled - Unspecified Error.

A copy of the code:

```
        clsDBConnector dbConnector = new clsDBConnector();
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        string sqlStr;
        dbConnector.Connect();
        sqlStr = " SELECT        MAX(EventID) AS MaxID" +
                 " FROM          Events";
        dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            EventID = Convert.ToInt16( dr[0].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        sqlStr = " SELECT        MemberID" +
                 " FROM          GroupMembers" +
                 " WHERE (GroupID = " + GroupID + ")";
        dr = dbConnector.DoSQL(sqlStr);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MemberID = Convert.ToInt16( dr[0].ToString());
            clsDBConnector dbConnectorInsert = new clsDBConnector();
            string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO EventsAtendees " +
                            "(MemberID, EventID) " +
                            "VALUES        (" + MemberID + ", " + EventID + ")";
            dbConnectorInsert.Connect();
            dbConnectorInsert.DoDML(cmdStr);
            dbConnectorInsert.close();
        }
        dr.Close();
```

I have taken out the custom fields and variables to make this more useable by everyone.

Comment: Is this the complete SQL you show or an abbreviation?

Comment: @trailmax an abbreviation so that it'd b more accessible to everyone.

Comment: @trailmax can put in full DML if needed

Comment: You'll need to show more code/context for anybody to be able to answer your question

Comment: @trailmax I've added more context

Comment: You realy should use sql parameters.

Comment: You can really do this as a single SQL Query. Lookup "Insert into select". Something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: What is clsDBConnector?

Comment: @DanielGrist And yes, sql parameters are a must-have: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: @Polyfun the connector to the database.

Comment: The error is occurring in the DML statement